# Why are the tension forces different?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider three cases that I've drawn. These are taken from my mechanics book. The ellipses are pulleys and the blocks are some weights and strings connect everything. The weight of the strings and pulleys as the friction between pulley and strings are neglected. In the third case there is a friction between the inclined plane and box. In each case except the last everything accelerates to the right while in the last everything is in equilibrium. Lets call the weight of the first block in the first case $m_A$ and the other $m_B$.

In the first case the tension force $S_1=\frac{2m_Am_Bg}{m_A+m_B}$ In the third case the tension force $S_3$ is as big as $F_3$.

The third case is similar to first case so it seems strange that the tension force is as big as $F_3$ in the third case.

In the second case the tension force is as big as $m_Bg$. Here the second block is replaced by a force that is equal to the gravitational force in first case. I don't understand how the tension force isn't the same as in the first case. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In case 2, if $F_2=m_Bg$ then the system is not in equilibrium (unless $m_A=m_B$) so you cannot conclude that $S_1 = F_2$. Instead, $S_1$ has the same value as in case 1.

In case 3, if there is an object on the right hand side (which your diagram suggests) then you cannot conclude that $S_3 = F_3$ - you have to take the weight of the right hand object into account. If the right hand object has mass $m_B$ *and* if is not accelerating then  $S_3 = F_3 + m_Bg$. This is different from case 1 and case 2 because you have both an applied force *and* a massive object on the right hand side.